# Unknown property 'ContactStandardController.Account'

Tags: visualforce, contact, standardcontroller

I hava a visualforce page in which standardController is Contact.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">

</apex:page>
<script>
        var company = {!URLENCODE(Account.Name)};//Error comes on this line
</script>
```

It is not allowing me to save the visualforce page and the error is

> Unknown property 'ContactStandardController.Account'

Comment: Try contact.Account.Name

Comment: You will also hit a compile error for the markup. Your script tags need to be within the *<apex:page></apex:page>* tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant call Account.Name directly.

Use the code below

```
    var company = {!URLENCODE(contact.Account.Name)};
```

instead of

```
    var company = {!URLENCODE(Account.Name)};
```